# Factoring polynomials when roots are external to the ring

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, roots, factoring, integral-extensions

I shall avoid maths script since I'm typing on a mobile, anyway I think I can do without.
I have a question about factoring polynomials over a ring.
Let's call R the ring in question.

It is clear to me that any root of a polynomial in R allows to factor the polynomial it by X minus the root. But when the root is in one of R's extensions, then X minus the root isn't a polynomial over R anymore, and factoring in R[X] loses its sense. But in some sense, which I do not understand, there seems to always be another polynomial, which IS in R[X], and that cancels out at the same root, by which you CAN factor.

To make this clear, consider for instance that R is ring of integers. Suppose we have a polynomial with 1/2 as a root. Then (X-1/2) isn't in Z[X] so factoring by it isn't suitable. Then, though, I heard a claim that any polynomial in Z[X] that has 1/2 as a root can be factored by (2X-1). But why is that true, cause saying that we can factor by any polynomial that has 1/2 as a root is clearly wrong. So how do we know that 2X-1 is a good choice ? I mean, if we chose multiples of (2X-1) we would reach a point where the coefficients of the cofactor can't be further divided.
Can anyone explain ?

Thanks !

Dan

Comment: See [minimal polynomial.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28field_theory%29)

Comment: I thought about that. But 2X-1 isn't monic ! Unless I've misunderstood the article

Comment: When you pass to $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ it differs from monic $\,x-1/2\,$ by a *unit* factor  $(= 2)$ and that suffices for our purposes (we can ignore units in divisibility problems).

Comment: Hmmm... Indeed, but 2 is a unit of Q[X], not one of Z[X]. So any ponynomial divisible by (X-1/2) is divisible by its unit multiples, IN Q[X]. But I still don't get why it is in Z[X]. Especially given that all non-zero constants are units of Q[X], yet surely you can't factor by anything of the form n(x-1/2) and still have integers on the other side (when n exceeds the gcd, also requires that the cofactor of X-1/2 has integral coefficients, and I don't see why that woild be the case... They even need to be even !)

Comment: Are you familiar with [Gauss's Lemma?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_%28polynomial%29)

Comment: I am not ! In fact an explantation can wait, but does anyone know a "rule" which tells you, given a root, by which polynomials (that also have that root) you can factor ?